# cakeDC comments plugin Element not found

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakedc

For those of you that are experienced with the cakeDC comments plugin, can I please get some guidance.

The output on my view page is this:

```
Element Not Found: Elements/Commentscomments/tree/main.ctp
```

I understand that it cannot find the correct folder because there is a missing forward slash while looking for the file.

The View code that is added to this page is:

```
<div id="post-comments">
    <?php $this->CommentWidget->options(array('allowAnonymousComment' => false));?>
    <?php echo $this->CommentWidget->display();?>
</div>
```

How could I go about fixing this issue?  I don't specifically know what to look for or where to look in terms of fixing the path issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell is that this plugin created by cakeDC has not been fully ported to work correctly with 2.X.  I Have set the specific paths of the elements that were causing this issue in the

```
public function display(){} controller found in the CommentWidgetHelper.php file.
```

There are a few other `$this->element()` calls that you will need to adjust.  It does not read them correctly from the comments plugin without changing these items.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this commit solved the problem for me: https://github.com/CakeDC/comments/commit/75cf8085fa96d1491cb31d2eed10b2ce18331e99